# How to create FTP account in Ubuntu 16.0 using PHP

Tags: php, ubuntu, ftp

I am going to create FTP accounts to all registered users. Each user should have folder inside **/var/www/html** folder.

I can already create folder:

```
<?php 
 exec('mkdir /var/www/html/test');
?>
```

and created the database after registering.

What I am trying to do next is to create an FTP user and point to their folder inside /var/www/html folder.

I tried this command but it doesn't work.

```
<?php 
 exec('adduser testftp');
?>
```

I've been doing this for few days already and searched on google but still not working. Does anybody know?

Comment: Don't use `exec()`, use PHP functions and libraries. So `exec('mkdir /var/www/html/test');` should be `mkdir('/var/www/html/test')` and for FTP have a look here: http://php.net/manual/en/book.ftp.php

Comment: Yeah, I tried that already. How about create FTP user? is there a function for it?

Comment: No, this is just an FTP client to connect to a FTP server. Do do really need to configure an FTP server? So your new users will connect to an FTP server natively and upload to your website? That doesn't seem to make much sense.

Comment: On my website, the users will register. And after registration, I will  automatically create their own FTP accounts like what hostings do.

Comment: Oh, ok, I understand, you really want them to use FTP to build their own website. You then need to configure your FTP server correctly to stay secure. The first thing you need to find out is which FTP server you will be running, because the configuration depends on that. For example: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-vsftpd-for-a-user-s-directory-on-ubuntu-16-04

Comment: Yeah, I have done this link also. This is manually adding. I want to add using PHP script.

Comment: Ok, so you're using vsftpd. That's useful information.